# Unable to submit form using Jquery + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to submit the following form using Jquery through the subscribe.php file and get the response from the PHP file.

I am trying to submit the form to a subscription list on Mailchimp and would like to display the response message that is received from Mailchimp through the subscribe.php ($result), on the html page. I am not very used to PHP and wondering how this can be solved.

I am getting the following:

```
post('lists/0b65107073/members', array( 'email_address' => $_POST["email"], 'status' => 'subscribed' )); if($result){ $status = $result["status"]; if($status == "subscribed"){ echo "Great! We will keep you updated on our progress."; } else{ echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again."; } } ?>
```

appended into the #SubscribeMessage div instead of getting the response for the submitted data. Also, the data is not submitted to mailchimp as expected. I am not sure whether this is an issue on the jquery or php side.

```
<form id="SubsribeForm1">
  <input id="emailAdd" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Hinterlasse Deine Email…" class="col-md-8 EmailInput" />
  <button id="SubscribeEmail" class="EmailSubmit" type="submit">Einreichen</button>
  <div id="SubscribeMessage"></div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#SubscribeEmail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'subscribe.php',
      data: {
        email : $('#emailAdd').val()
      },
      success:function (data) {
        $("#SubscribeMessage").append(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

subscribe.php

```
<?php
require("_mc.php");

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('6385e94cf70076a289c1dyd656920f49-us13');
$result = $MailChimp->post('lists/0b6510i85f/members', array(
                'email_address'     => $_POST["email"],
                'status'            => 'subscribed'
            ));

if($result){
    $status = $result["status"];

    if($status == "subscribed"){
        echo "Great! We will keep you updated on our progress.";
    }
    else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: where did you add your jquery library file?

Comment: Instead of handling the `click` event of the `#SubscribeEmail` button, handle the `submit` event of the `#SubsribeForm1`. This way you avoid possible page reloads.

Comment: What result are you getting? You only stated what you want to happen, I need to know how it is acting currently.

Comment: @kirangadhvi I have included jQuery and not getting any errors on the jQuery side

Comment: Try naming your instance of `MailChimp` something else, like `$mailChimp` or just `$mc`. It's possible you have a conflict due to the class name and instance variable being identical.

Comment: @jdgregson have tried it, still no luck

Comment: Hmmm, as a test, try commenting out what you have and setting the PHP to make a post request exactly like DrewM's API documentation, especially the `[]` array convention and the trailing comma in the array: `$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => 'davy@example.com',
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
            ]);`

Comment: It does not seem to be going through, do you think it is an issue from the jQuery side?

Comment: It shouldn't be be on the jQuery side. The jQuery is successfully appending what the PHP file returned, so it is all working as expected. The weird thing is that it sounds like the PHP file is actually displaying the PHP code after `$MailChimp->`, which is VERY strange. Are you positive that the PHP code you posted above is what jQuery is getting back? What I would suggest is to add `echo $MailChimp->getLastError();` before and after your post request, leaving the test from my last comment as the post request, and visiting `subscribe.php` in the browser and see what it prints.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just realized PHP is not properly executed on my system and non of the commands work. Trying to figure out that issue.

Comment: It kind of seemed like a PHP parsing issue. No matter how bad an error you get, PHP should never, ever print the last half of the page. That is a serious security issue. But you're welcome, I hope you can get that sorted out.